# Retrieving data with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am currently trying to get users with Mongoose, but when I try to move the function to a separate module, it throws some errors which are not very helpful. So some introduction:

If I use in the controller like this:

```
exports.index2 = function(req, res) {
Users.find(function(err, users){
    if (err){
        console.log("ERR");
    }
    console.log(users);
    res.json(users);
});};
```

Everything is working fine, but when I try to separate it like this, it doesn't work.

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {  
   UsersModel.findAll(function(users, err){
        if (!err){
            console.log(users);  <--- this is not showing
            res.send(users);
        }else
            console.log(err);
   });
};
```

// this is in the Model, which is required in the Controller

```
findAll: function() {
    User.find(function(err, users){
        if (err){
            console.log("ERR");
        }
        //console.log(users);  <--- this is showing
        return users;
    });
},
```

I was getting undefined, because I was trying to run findAll sync and not async. After "taking care" of this, the **undefined** disappeared, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're passing in a callback function to the findAll() function...

```
UsersModel.findAll(function(users, err){ ... })
```

...but the findAll() method never makes use of this callback to return any values. Based on how it's being consumed, it would be expected to be defined more along these lines:

```
findAll: function(callback) {
    User.find(function(err, users){
        callback(err, users);
    });
}
```

Additionally, your branching in the 2nd example is such that there's a path where the response is never sent:

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {  
    UsersModel.findAll(function(users, err){
        if (!err){
            console.log(users);  <--- this is not showing
            res.send(users);
        }else
            console.log(err);
   });
};
```

Unlike in your first example, the function's only invocation of res.send is made in the success case. So if there's an error, you're logging it, then the function exits, and the client is never sent a response (at least not by this handler).

Basically, the issue you're having is with managing callbacks. Here's [a good resource](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/) on the JavaScript callback pattern if you're interested.

Cheers.